# interesting Delphi open-source applications/projects (not components/component packs!)

Tags: delphi, open-source

I'd like to know what interesting **open-source** projects written in Delphi (or FreePascal) you know?
I'm not asking for components/components packs, I know there were questions for that.

Please do not duplicate answers, vote them up instead ;)
Please do not point components/packs/closed-source projects.
Please provide at least word of description ;)

Two examples from me:

- PyScripter - Python IDE written in Delphi - hosted at google code (*)
- HeidiSQL - MySQL Frontend - http://www.heidisql.com/

(*)sorry, as a new user I can't post more than one link :(

Comment: This ought to be community wiki

Comment: Why, @Scott? Can *you* articulate when a post should be CW? So many others can't. There's never been a good explanation.

Comment: Fair enough.  My opinion is that there is not a "right" answer here, it is just a place to list a bunch of interesting links and so it doesn't really make sense to dole out rep for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a list of quite a few of them in the [Good Quality Applications Built With Delphi](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Quality_Applications_Built_With_Delphi) wiki.

Answer (score 5):

Context : http://www.contexteditor.org ,an excellent text Editor more efficient than NotePad++ for very large files.

AxBase : http://sourceforge.net/projects/axbase/ ,a MDB (and ADO) database front end.

PyScripter : http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/ a well known Python IDE.

Comment: Frustratingly, this doesn't appear to compile as it resides in its repository, even after I remove the hard-coded drive references in the project options.

Answer (score 4):

- Lazarus/FPC  (FPC and Lazarus together are the largest public Object Pascal codebase I know)
- Ultrastar deluxe   (singstar like karaoke app) http://ultrastardx.sourceforge.net/

In general, see the application galleries for FPC and Lazarus (though they are not updated enough.

- http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_Applications/Projects_Gallery
- http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Application_Gallery

Most notably Hedgewars (game: worms clone) has some popularity on Linux: http://www.hedgewars.org/

Also the Lazarus port of Delphi app MRIcron is popular: 
http://www.cabiatl.com/mricro/mricron/

Tony Maro's checkbook tracker used to be a quite popular app for a while, but I don't know its current status: http://www.ossramblings.com/cbtracker

Answer (score 3):

One open source app I like and use a lot is the [XanaNews](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/xananews.htm) news reader.  More recent versions are available [here](http://xananews.techtips.com.br/).

A search for [Delphi on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?words=delphi&sort=score&sortdir=desc&offset=25&type_of_search=soft) turns up quite a few, but you'll have to wade through them to pick out the applications vs components/libraries.

the [wiki page for Delphi applications](http://delphi.wikia.com/index.php/Good_Quality_Applications_Built_With_Delphi) has a section specifically for [open source projects](http://delphi.wikia.com/index.php/Good_Quality_Applications_Built_With_Delphi#Delphi_Open-Source_Applications.2FProjects).

Answer (score 2):

Check for example

[Ares Galaxy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aresgalaxy/) (file sharing)
[Portable Apps manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/)

Just make a search on sourceforge for Delphi projects...

Answer (score 2):

[XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[Dev-PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/devphp/) is a well-featured IDE for PHP. Fast and powerful, it is easy to use and has a lot of cool features : class browser, scripts preview, integration with PHP parsers, PHP-GTK library, and Xdebug of course. Dev-PHP-usb slips even into your pocket

[Dev-C++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/) is an full-featured Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for Win32. It uses GCC, Mingw or Cygwin as compiler and libraries set.

Answer (score 0):

Peazip : http://sourceforge.net/projects/peazip/ excellent compression/archive Manager, now in Free Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

[StarUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/staruml/), a great UML/MDA model editing tool, also an excellent example of how to design and code such a large project. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

dxbx http://sourceforge.net/projects/dxbx/ a port of cxbx which is an xbox emulator for the pc

Answer (score 0):

1. [WorldVistA EHR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/worldvista-ehr/) : Electronic Health Record
2. [HosXP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hosxp/) : Electronic Health Record, (thaï only)
3. [ExtPascal](http://code.google.com/p/extpascal/) : Object Pascal wrapper/binding for Ext JS (Delphi, FreePascal/Lazarus)
4. [osFinancials](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osfinancials/) : Accounting Software
5. [SuperObject (JSON) and UIB (Unified Interbase)](http://www.progdigy.com)